# Is it possible to have dot product of two continuous vector fields to be discontinuous at a point?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are two vectors in $R^3$ and field-wise continuous at point $x_0$. It is possible to have $a.b$ discontinuous at $x_0$?. If yes, could you cite any example.

Comment: Question: what do you mean by dot product of two vector fields? As in if you had fields $f,g:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, defining the dot product of the two to be the function $f\cdot g: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $$(f \cdot g)(x,y)=f(x,y)\cdot g(x,y)?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

If the fields are continuous at $x_0$, their components are continuous there. But their dot product is the sum of products of their components, and multiplication and addition of continuous functions preserves continuity.